# React Native 0.60 upgrade: Unknown type name 'MutexType'

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm in the process of upgrading my app to React Native v0.60.4. I did all the steps from documentation and upgrade helper, but when trying to build an app for iOS, the build fails for `glog` with the following errors:

```
.../app/ios/Pods/glog/src/base/mutex.h:147:3: error: Need to implement mutex.h for your architecture, or #define NO_THREADS
# error Need to implement mutex.h for your architecture, or #define NO_THREADS
  ^
.../app/ios/Pods/glog/src/base/mutex.h:188:3: error: unknown type name 'MutexType'
  MutexType mutex_;
```

Couldn't find any solutions on what's going wrong.

My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

target '...app' do
  # Uncorm mment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-DevSupport', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/React'
  pod 'React-fishhook', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/fishhook'
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'React-RCTWebSocket', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/WebSocket'

  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'

  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  # Pods for ...app
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 5.15.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'

  target '...appTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  use_native_modules!
end
```

Comment: https://github.com/google/glog/blob/master/src/base/mutex.h See this and compare the documents.

Comment: Struggling with this from past 1 week. anybody found any solution ?

Comment: Any luck people?

Comment: Still happening with XCode 14

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by adding `define NO_THREADS` to the bottom in file `config.h` in `iOS/Pods/glog/src/config.h` . But I am still having another issues related to glog. I am not sure if this is the right way to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Yeah, I've tried this way as well, but then glog was failing with different issue.

Comment: Any solution you guys found?

Answer (score 1):

For future Googlers, this occurs because (from what I can tell) the configure script RN generates during `pod install` can't properly detect whether pthreads support is included on macOS. This appears to be due to some difference between Xcode 11 and Xcode 12 because people who have downgraded said the problem went away.

In any case, the following worked for me:

- Open `ios/Pods/Flipper-Glog/src/config.h` and ADD `#define HAVE_PTHREAD 1` anywhere in the file and change the `HAVE_RWLOCK` flag to `#define HAVE_RWLOCK 1` as well
- Open `ios/Pods/glog/src/config.h` and do the same. You need to do both libraries.

Making this change made things work for me. This isn't just forcing it to work, it's correcting something that was previously working. I verified in older projects that these fields were correctly set (and pthread support is widespread among macOS, the simulators and iOS).

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to add `-DNO_THREADS` to your `OTHER_CPLUSPLUSFLAGS` in your XCode Config. If you modify the `config.h` file, then the changes will get wiped out the next time you run `pod install`.